# Can't we declare a string datatype in C++ with its size?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was declaring a string in C++ and got an error.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    int t;
    cin>>t;

    while(t--){
        int n;
        cin>>n;

        string encoded(10);
```

The error says:
`no instance of constructor "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string [with _CharT=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (int)C/C++(289)`

What is the meaning of this error and why can't we declare a string datatype like this?

Comment: Don't post images of text (least of all code). Always post code copy-pasted as text. And build errors should be copy-pasted in full and complete, including any possible informational notes.

Comment: Also please don't use competition sites as a learning or teaching resource, unless all you want to learn are really bad habits. That [`<bits/stdc++.h>` header is one such example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h). Get [some good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and take a couple of classes, and learn properly.

Comment: You could use a [different constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) (since the one that you want doesn't exist), e.g. `string variable1(10,'\0');`. This behaves like an empty c-style string, but already has memory for 10 characters alloocated.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I have added the changes as mentioned by you. Thank You.

Answer (score 2):

`std::string` constructors can be tricky. It helps to use a good reference, such as the [cppreference wiki](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string).

It's not clear exactly what "a string of length 10" should be without providing other details. You might want,

- ten whitespace characters, like `std::string variable1( 10, ' ' );`
- a string variable which is empty, but can get up to ten characters without allocating additional memory, like `std::string variable1; variable1.reserve( 10 );`

If you use the generic container methods of `std::string` such as `resize`, or pass `'\0'` NUL characters instead of whitespace, then those NULs will be treated as part of the string. That could break usual text-oriented functionality and cause conflicting results from C and C++ based logic.

If you really want exactly ten characters starting as NUL, and *not* a class with an `append` operation and such, then try an array like `std::array<char,10> variable1` or `char variable1[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
string str(10, '\0');
```

The error message means that the constructor of "String" does not expect there to be a parameter in its initialization.  You cannot set the size of the string when initializing it like that in C++.

Comment: Well, there are alternative constructors, which will at least come near to what the OP wants to achieve.

Comment: The question was what the error message is and why the OP cannot instantiate it like that though

Comment: Sure, but that doesn't hinder you to add possible alternatives to your answer, no?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.resize()` function

```
string str;
  
str.resize(10);
```